# What is "Open and Save Panel service"?

Tags: cpu, services, performance, macos

I put my computer to sleep and everything was normal, but when I woke it up again, the CPU and fans started to run at 100 %. This is what I saw in Activity Monitor:

[image]

**What is this and why does it use so much CPU??**

None of these applications had any open/save dialogue open, now was I using QuickLook (space bar on a selected file in Finder) I have seen this, but only for a single application, once or twice before. Waiting a few minutes didn't change anything and a "regular" kill didn't help, but force kill worked.

Comment: Processes in red are Not Responding to user input, so they may have got stuck or frozen. If this just happens once, I would forget it. If it happens regularly, I would do more investigating.

Comment: @benwiggy I know. That is why I included the screen shot. It happens from time to time, on all three of my computers. Maybe once a month, once every other month or so.